# How to get all piped in objects at once when using Begin/Process/End blocks?

Tags: powershell

I am stuck on a learning project I have set out on, the objective here was meant for me to learn this whole the `Begin`, `Process` and `End` blocks concept

My project consists of a function, that will let the user open a single Firefox window with a specific profile and optionally open one or more web pages via  `.url` files saved on the `C:` drive. This is what I have so far:

```
Function Ask-Web{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('andy','andrew','halley', "hanna")]
        [Array]$FirefoxProfile = 'Andy',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Position = 2)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('DIYhome','DIYreddit','DIYexchange','DIYall', 'SelectWithFZF')]
        [Array]$Pages
    )
Begin{
    $FavouritePages = [ordered]@{
    DIYhome     = "https://www.diyUK.com"
    DIYreddit   = "https://www.reddit.com/r/DIY/submit"
    DIYexchange = "https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask"
    # DIYall  Will handle this later
    } 
    
    [array]$Pages = If($Pages -eq "SelectWithFZF"){Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\Ask Pages\" -Filter *.url*| FZF}Else{$FavouritePages."$Pages"}  ;the FZF utility will store all selected items into $Pages variable
    }
End{. 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' -p $FirefoxProfile $Pages}

}
```

The function is supposed to let the user select pages via argument completions, pre provide a web page from the pipeline or make a selection from folder `C:\temp\Ask Pages\` using the utility  [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

In all instances, the user is expected to provide one or more pages/urls:

```
Ask-Web -FirefoxProfile andy -Pages DIYhome,DIYreddit,DIYexchange    ; Open a singe Firefox window, with profile "Andy" and the pages DIYhome,DIYreddit and DIYexchange
Ask-Web -FirefoxProfile hanna -Pages DIYhome                         ; Open a singe Firefox window, with profile "Hanna" and the page DIYhome
Ask-Web -FirefoxProfile andrew -Pages SelectWithFZF                  ; Open a singe Firefox window, with profile "Andrew" and all the pages that were selected with FZF
Get-ChildItem .\Diy -filter *.url* | Ask-Web -FirefoxProfile hanna   ; Open a singe Firefox window, with profile "Hanna" and with all the pages provided by the pipeline
```

Where I seem to be stuck is getting PowerShell to give me all the pipeline input at once, rather than one at a time or the last pipeline item, which is what I get with the above function.

If I go with `Process{. 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' -p $FirefoxProfile $Pages}` then PowerShell will open a Firefox window for every item there is in `$Pages`, yet with `End{. 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' -p $FirefoxProfile $Pages}` only the last item in `$Pages` gets opened.

I tried:

```
Function Ask-Web{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('andy','andrew','halley', "hanna")]
        [Array]$FirefoxProfile = 'Andy',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Position = 2)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('DIYhome','DIYreddit','DIYexchange','DIYall', 'SelectWithFZF')]
        [Array]$Pages
    )
    Process{[Array]$Pages += @($input)}  
    End{$Pages}
}
```

With `Ask-Web -FirefoxProfile andy -Pages DIYhome,DIYreddit,DIYexchange`, in the `End` block I get :

```
DIYhome
DIYreddit
DIYexchange
```

But with `'DIYhome','DIYreddit','DIYexchange'|Ask-Web -FirefoxProfile andy` in the `End` block I get :

```
DIYexchange
DIYexchange
```

If I forego all the `Begin`, `Process` and `End` blocks with:

```
Function Ask-Web{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('andy','andrew','halley', "hanna")]
        [Array]$FirefoxProfile = 'Andy',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Position = 2)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('DIYhome','DIYreddit','DIYexchange','DIYall', 'SelectWithFZF')]
        [Array]$Pages
    )
    $input
}
```

I get consistent results, all the elements of array `$Pages` are handed at once, regardless of how the user provided them. How can I do the same but with the `Begin`, `Process` and `End` blocks?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tbh, your use case might not be a great learning example for the pipeline, but if you *really* want to pursue it you should initialise a new *local* variable in your ```BEGIN``` block - e.g. ```$items = @()```, accumulate pipeline items in your ```PROCESS``` block (e.g. ```$items += $_```) and then do something *once* with *all* of the items in your ```END``` block. Note that you should avoid ```+=``` for arrays in production code for performance reasons, but it’s probably fine for your exercise…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, the recommended one is to collect all input passed through the pipeline with a `List<T>`, this is done in the `process` block of your function. Then after all pipeline input has been collected you can start Firefox in your `end` block.

Main reason to use `List<T>` to collect pipeline input as opposed to a `System.Array` (`@()` and `+=`) is because arrays are of a [fixed size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-add?view=net-7.0#remarks) and PowerShell has to recreate it each time we add a new element to it which makes it very inefficient. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle) and [PowerShell scripting performance considerations - Array addition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations?view=powershell-7.3#array-addition) for more details on this.

```bash
function Test-Pipeline {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Array] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
    process {
        $list.AddRange($InputObject)
    }
    end {
        if($list.Count) {
            # do stuff here with `$list`
            $list.ToArray()
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItem | Test-Pipeline
```

The `List<T>` in this case is necessary because PowerShell will pass one object at a time through the pipeline, this is what's known as [**One-at-a-time processing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3#one-at-a-time-processing). Using [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) is not a recommended option in this case because 1. your function is an [advanced one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2) and the use of this automatic variable is not recommended in advanced functions. 2. Using `$input` would mean that your function only works from pipeline only unless you work around it.

The second option, and the not recommended one, is to pass the result of `Get-ChildItem` through the pipeline without enumerating it. For this you can use [`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.3#-noenumerate) or the [comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#comma-operator-):

```bash
function Test-Pipeline {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Array] $InputObject
    )

    end {
        $InputObject
    }
}

# option 1:
Write-Output (Get-ChildItem) -NoEnumerate | Test-Pipeline
# option 2:
, (Get-ChildItem) | Test-Pipeline
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have a scoping problem with your `$Pages` variable.

When passing via the pipeline, the `$Pages` variable gets reset to the latest value of the enumeration. This is why you are only getting the last value twice. Basically the Process block sees a new `$Pages` every time around, so on the last round, you are adding the latest `$input` to it.

I think the simplest solution is to introduce a new variable that you then use in the End block:

```
Function Ask-Web{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('andy','andrew','halley', "hanna")]
        [Array]$FirefoxProfile = 'Andy',
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Position = 2)]
        [ArgumentCompletions('DIYhome','DIYreddit','DIYexchange','DIYall', 'SelectWithFZF')]
        [Array]$Pages
    )
    Process{
        write-host "Process: $Pages"
        [Array]$AllPages += $Pages
        }  
    End{
        
        $AllPages }
}
```